# How to make triangle div border using html & css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using html, css, and bootstrap.

I have 2 horizontal divs:

```
<style>
  .panel1 {
   background-image: url("panel1.png");
   background-position: right bottom;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
  }

 .panel2 {
   background-image: url("panel2.jpg");
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
 }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid panel1">
  ...div content...
</div>



<div class="container-fluid panel2">
  ...div content...
</div>
```

They each have a background image, and I would like them to meet up in a triangular manner like [this site](http://www.solarcity.com)

[image]

Comment: What's _"angular div"_? Read [ask] and create a [mcve], and no - 2 divs are not a valid example

Comment: these are angular divs [here](http://www.solarcity.com). on this site they have these angles or triangles to divide the page contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use two div below the image as follows,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...div content...
</div>

<div class="leftBorder"></div>
<div class="rightBorder"></div>
```

and its CSS,

```
.leftBorder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 5.1vw 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    z-index: 499;
}
.rightBorder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 49.9vw;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5.1vw 0 0 50.1vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
    z-index: 499;
}
```

This should work.